# Redirect method call in wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

How to redirect a wcf method call to another method in wcf.

lets say a user call wcf method `GetDetail(para1,para2)` and we redirect it to `GetMyDetail(para1, para2)`.

So basically for user its `GetDetail` method, but in wcf side *instead of* `Getdetail` method we will call `GetMyDetail` method and send result back to user.

on google i found some article saying that this can be achieve using `IClientOperationSelector` but was not able to found any example.

This is not for single method, a mapping will be written in webconfig/xml file for call forwarding method and parameters.

Comment: why you are not just call `GetMyDetail` inside `GetDetail`

Comment: GetMyDetail is not exposed to outer world as well as may have less/more parameters..

Comment: It does not matter GetMyDetail is not exposed, since you are calling inside GetDetail

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can simply return the outcome of GetMyDetail inside GetDetail. I don't see the problem actually...

Comment: It has more parameter as well as method will be selected based on parameter values..

Comment: The thing is we can't edit GetDetail method, its already in use, and we want to put some selector over it so a call can diverted to any method based on parameter passed into that method..

Comment: So you already know what to do / achieve. Still see no problem. Aren't you able to divert the call based on the parameters for GetDetail? I suppose return Types of initial method and "diverted" methods are the same...although. Take a look at versioning WCF services might also help you.

Comment: Actually it is not only for single method a mapping of method call switching will be written in webconfig/xml file and based on that the calls will be diverted to different methods..

Answer (score 0):

You can call this way

```
public int GetDetail(para1,para2)
{

   return GetMyDetail(para1, para2...)
}
```

or user function overloading

```
[OperationContract(Name="GetDetail")]
string GetMyDetail(int para1,int para2);
//Initail method
[OperationContract(Name = "GetDetail")]
string GetDetail(string para1, string para2);
```